# delete am image from a PDF file using PDFbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am attempting to delete images from a PDF using java and PDFbox.   The images are not inline, and the PDF does not have patterns or forms.  The pdf file contains 2 images.  The PDFdebugger tool shows Resources >> XObject >> IM3 and IM5. The problem is: I display the output pdf file and the images are not deleted.

```
public class DeleteImage {
    public static void removeImages(String pdfFile) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFile));

        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
            pdResources.getXObjectNames().forEach(propertyName -> {
                if(!pdResources.isImageXObject(propertyName)) {
                    return;
                }
                PDXObject o;
                try {
                    o = pdResources.getXObject(propertyName);
                    if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                        System.out.println("propertyName" + propertyName);
                        page.getCOSObject().removeItem(propertyName);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            for (COSName name :  page.getResources().getPatternNames()) {
                PDAbstractPattern pattern = page.getResources().getPattern(name);
                System.out.println("have pattern");
            }
              
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
            parser.parse();
            List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
            System.out.println("original tokens size" + tokens.size());
            List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();

            for(int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object token = tokens.get( j );
                if( token instanceof Operator ) {
                    Operator op = (Operator)token;

                    System.out.println("operation" + op.getName());
                    //find image - remove it
                    if( op.getName().equals("Do") ) {
                        System.out.println("op equals Do");
                        newTokens.remove(newTokens.size()-1);
                        continue;
                    } else if ("BI".equals(op.getName())) {
                        System.out.println("inline -- op equals BI");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("op not quals Do");
                    }
                }
                newTokens.add(token);
            }

            PDDocument newDoc = new PDDocument();
            PDPage newPage = newDoc.importPage(page);
            newPage.setResources(page.getResources());

            System.out.println("tokens size" + newTokens.size());
            PDStream newContents = new PDStream(newDoc);
            OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter( out );
            writer.writeTokens( newTokens);
            out.close();
            newPage.setContents( newContents );
        }

        document.save("RemoveImage.pdf");
        document.close();
    }

    public static void remove(String pdfFile) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFile));
        PDResources resources = null;
        
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            resources = page.getResources();

            for (COSName name : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
                PDXObject xobject = resources.getXObject(name);
                
                if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    System.out.println("have image");
                    removeImages(pdfFile);
                }
            }
        }
        document.save("RemoveImage.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### If You Call `remove`...

In `remove` you

- load the PDF into `document`,
- iterate over the pages of `document`, and for each page

  - iterate over the XObject resources, and for each Xobject

    - check whether it is an image Xobject, and if it is

      - call `removeImages` which loads the same original file, processes it, and saves the result as "RemoveImage.pdf".
- After all that processing you save the unchanged `document` to "RemoveImage.pdf".

So in that last step you **overwrite any changes you may have done in `removeImages`** and end up with your original file in "RemoveImage.pdf"!

#### If You Call `removeImages` Directly...

In `removeImages` you do some changes but there are certain issues:

- Whenever you find an image Xobject resource, you attempt to remove it from the page directly

  ```
  page.getCOSObject().removeItem(propertyName);
  ```

  but the image Xobject resource is not a direct child of the `page`, it is managed by `pdResources`, so you should remove it from there.
- You remove *all* **Do** instructions from the page content, not only those for image Xobjects, so you probably remove more than you wanted.

Comment: Do you know the syntax to remove the image from the resource ?

Comment: *"the syntax to remove the image from the resource"* - to remove the image Xobject with name `COSName name` from the resources in `PDResources resources` simply call `resources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT).removeItem(name)`...